# Bootstrap Popover Keep HTML

Tags: popover, bootstrap-popover

How to save popover contents upon re-initializing? Here is my code and the popup contains a form. I want to keep the form values if user comes back to after filling some info...

```js
$(this).popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'manual',
    placement: 'bottom',
    content: function () {
        var $contents = $('#popover_template').html();
        return $contents;
    }
}).popover('toggle');
```

I don't want any modal window etc. Is there a way to keep the contents of a form even if the popover is reopen.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show the markup for `#popover_template` too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "hidden" event to detect when your popover closes, then set its content back to your #popover_template div.

```
$(this).popover({
  // your initialization code
}).popover('toggle')
  .on("hidden", function(e) {
     $('#popover_template').html($(this).html());
   });
```

References

[How to attach a function to popover dismiss event (Twitter Bootstrap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215995/how-to-attach-a-function-to-popover-dismiss-event-twitter-bootstrap)

[Bootstrap modal popover hide on close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310917/bootstrap-modal-popover-hide-on-close)

[Bootstrap Popover - Save HTML on close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905975/bootstrap-popover-save-html-on-close)

Comment: It brings the text on button that open popover not the popover.

Comment: Oh sorry. Just replace `$(this).html()` with the html from the popover.